# How to perform SELECT FOR UPDATE with SKIP LOCKED on MySQL with Django

Tags: mysql, django, pessimistic-locking

I have a **Django** project which uses a **MySQL v5.5** backend with **InnoDB** storage.
To avoid race condition updates in DB, I'm using select_for_update to lock the rows.
Now if this lock stays for a long time, any queries on the locked rows will timeout.
I want to avoid this with one of the following options:

1. Skip the rows which are locked, similar to `SKIP LOCKED` option.
2. Return immediately if some rows you're querying are locked, similar to `NOWAIT` option.
3. Reduce the lock wait timeout period for specific queries.

How do I perform any of these with Django ORM?

Answer (score 3):

from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/):

> You can also ignore locked rows by using select_for_update(skip_locked=True)

Comment: From the documentation `Currently, the postgresql, oracle, and mysql database backends support select_for_update(). However, MySQL doesn’t support the nowait and skip_locked arguments.` and I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Update April 2023, according to Django documentation, MariaDB 10.6+ supports the skip_locked argument, and MySQL 8.0.1+ supports the nowait, skip_locked, and of arguments.